# close react packer after xcode build

Tags: xcode, react-native

We have working Mac as CI server. We build our iOS add with fastlane (gym).

React packager remains opened after xcode build, or xcode archive (production build).

How to close it automatically after xcode archive?

I just went to lsof + kill script which kills process, But terminal remains opened with mesage `Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window`.

`` kill -9 `lsof -a -c node -c watchman $PROJECT_DIR $PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/react-native/packager` ``

Link to source file, which is launchced: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/launchPackager.command

Any other workarouns?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, It seems that I resolved this trouble.

---

UPD. just export `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` variable

### https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8fd2d7d17caa4bc719583058f2e4113788fab7cb

---

This command is started only when react-native server is *not* running.

So, my solution is: open this process as a job, build project, and teminate job and other processes which a watching on a dir.

`` react-native start &
fastlane ios build
kill $!
kill -9 `lsof -a -c node -c watchman $PROJECT_DIR $PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/react-native/packager` ``